# MySql not accessible by root user

Tags: shell, permissions, root, mysql

I have a local MySql server. It is started as I can access it with my local user like

```
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 66
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> exit
```

just fine but when i try with root, I keep getting this:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

***edit***

Also this doesn't work (after running `sudo mysql_install_db`
):

```
$ /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'MyPass'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Comment: [If using Debian or Ubuntu, and you want to reset everything and the tables and connect.](http://askubuntu.com/q/696964/29097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

for a password prompt.

If that does not work then perhaps refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760177/access-denied-for-root-user-in-mysql-command-line